# Different Behavior When Entity Deleted Directly and From Parent Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF core and I want to track deletion of entity. Now when any entity get deleted at that time using ChangeTracking I record that entity and also it is required to record it parent entity.

In this scenario I have took simple example. In this Company and Department has one to many relation.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class SimpleDbContext 
    : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }  

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(cc => cc.Departments).WithOne(cc => cc.Company);            
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=sampletracking;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        foreach(var item in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if(item.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                foreach(var itemRef in item.References)
                {
                    if (!itemRef.IsLoaded)
                        itemRef.Load();
                }
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Entties

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Prepare record.

```
using (SimpleDbContext simpleDbContext = new SimpleDbContext())
{
    Company company = new Company();
    company.CompanyName = "Company-1";
    company.Departments = new List<Department>();
    company.Departments.Add(new Department() { DepartmentName = "Department-1" });
    company.Departments.Add(new Department() { DepartmentName = "Department-2" });
    simpleDbContext.Add(company);
    await simpleDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Scenario 1 : Delete Child entity direct.

```
using (SimpleDbContext simpleDbContext = new SimpleDbContext())
{
    var department = simpleDbContext.Departments.Where(cc => cc.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    simpleDbContext.Remove(department);
    await simpleDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

In this scenario when savechange called, Change tracker detect the delete and when It load references ( so parent entity) then it successfully load.

Scenario 2: Delete from Parent

```
using (SimpleDbContext simpleDbContext = new SimpleDbContext())
{
    var company = simpleDbContext.Companies
        .Include(cc => cc.Departments)
        .Where(cc => cc.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

    company.Departments.RemoveAll(cc => cc.Id == 2);
    
    await simpleDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

In this scenario entity delete is being detected but when it try to load reference, it is always null.

Why if same entity delete from same collection it behave differently ?

Comment: I would think that the change tracking can only track changes to entities it is managing which is why scenario 1 works. In scenario 2, you're basically issuing a delete directly to the database, the context doesn't need to do anything other than send to the DB.

Comment: In second scenario , I want to know what is parent of that entity in order to Audit. Is there any better way because change tracking detect entity change but If I don't link with parent then I am not able to find that root entity is being change.